# how to solve angular error TS1127: Invalid character

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 9. I created a restapi service ts, and I added my logic code there, so there is no issue or error in my restapi service. I am facing an error when I import my restapi service in  login components ts. I created a restapi service in app folder, where my app routing and app modules are present. I want to import my restapi service into `login.component.ts`, which is present in login folder

I am getting an error at this line

```
import { RestapiService } from '../restapi.service';
```

The error is:

```
ERROR in src/app/restapi.service.ts:5:1 - error TS1127: Invalid character.
5 � providedIn: 'root'   src/app/restapi.service.ts:9:1 - error TS1127: Invalid character.
9 � constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }   src/app/restapi.service.ts:12:1 - error TS1127: Invalid character.
12 � const headers = new HttpHeaders({ Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password) });    src/app/restapi.service.ts:13:1
- error TS1127: Invalid character.
13 � return this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/",{headers,responseType: 'text' as 'json'})    src/app/restapi.service.ts:16:1 - error TS1127: Invalid character.
16 � getUsers() {    src/app/restapi.service.ts:17:1 - error TS1127: Invalid character.
17 � � let username='Nilmani'    src/app/restapi.service.ts:17:3 - error TS1127: Invalid character.
17 � � let username='Nilmani'
      src/app/restapi.service.ts:18:1 - error TS1127: Invalid character.
18 � � let password='jglkm@123'    src/app/restapi.service.ts:18:3 - error TS1127: Invalid character.
18 � � let password='jglkm@123'
      src/app/restapi.service.ts:19:1 - error TS1127: Invalid character.
19 � � const headers = new HttpHeaders({ Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password) });    src/app/restapi.service.ts:19:3
- error TS1127: Invalid character.
19 � � const headers = new HttpHeaders({ Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password) });
      src/app/restapi.service.ts:20:1 - error TS1127: Invalid character.
20 � �return �this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/dashboard",{headers});    src/app/restapi.service.ts:20:3 - error TS1127: Invalid character.
20 � �return �this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/dashboard",{headers});
      src/app/restapi.service.ts:20:11 - error TS1127: Invalid character.
20 � �return �this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/dashboard",{headers});
              src/app/restapi.service.ts:21:1 - error TS1127: Invalid character.
21 � }
```

login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { RestapiService } from '../restapi.service'; 

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-dashboard',
      templateUrl: 'login.component.html'
    })
    export class LoginComponent implements OnInit { 
      username: string;
      password: string;
      message: any

      constructor(private service: RestapiService,private router:Router) { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

      doLogin() {
        let resp = this.service.login(this.username, this.password);
        resp.subscribe(data => {
          this.message = data;
         this.router.navigate(["/home"])
        });
      }
    }
```

restapi.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RestapiService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

login(username:string,password:string){
  const headers = new HttpHeaders({ Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password) });
  return this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/",{headers,responseType: 'text' as 'json'})
}

  getUsers() {
    let username='Nilmani'
    let password='jglkm@123'
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password) });
   return  this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/dashboard",{headers});
  }
}
```

Comment: what the method btoa stand for. Also you missing ';' in first two statements in getUsers() method.

Answer (score 1):

RestApiService - I believe the code is copy-pasted for which it might be having some invisible characters making the compiler to throw error

Try pasting the code to notepad (or any editor which doesn't support markup)  first and then paste it back to your editor. Or better try to write the code from scratch and see if it works!